# How to fetch single model with Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

In Backbone context, I want to fetch some 'meta'-data in a JSON without a collection:

```
/data/meta.json 
{
  "name": "Patrick Mulder",
  "title": "SW Developer"
}
```

How do I fetch this into a model, such that I could do:

```
var meta = new MetaItem();
meta.fetch()
console.log(meta.name)  // <- or console.log(meta.get('name') ?
```

With my attempt:

```
    var MetaItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
      urlRoot : '/data/meta.json',
      parse: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          return response;
      }
    });
```

I get 'undefined' for any of the properties... anyone knows why?

Comment: what does the xhr response show in dev tools?

Comment: oh, the learning here is that I need to do:  meta.get('name') instead of meta.name ... ok, solved

Answer (score 0):

the model attributes is read with:

meta.get('name')

not with meta.name

Comment: And you need to wait until the `fetch` gets something from the server.